# Send mail from result (should be easy)

Tags: email, certificate, invoke-command

I have built a script to check for local machine certificates from a certain issuer expiring within 400.000 days (to get a hit when testing it) on remote server, but i cant just figure out how to get the result to send the actual email as experimenting with pipes after (and in) the IF statements doesnt seem to work.
I have been googling quiet alot (ofcourse) but as I'm new to Powershell and some code is difficult at times to interpret.

I am looking for something like; if $OutputFromtheIFStatement | Measure-Object -gt 0 { Send email using $SendReportNow.}

My code:

```
$Servers = 'testserver1,'testserver2'
$Threshold = 400000 
$Deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($Threshold)
$MailSMTP = '-SmtpServer smtpserver.domain.com -Port 25'
$MailTo = "receiversmailaddress@company.com"
$MailFrom = "sendersmailaddress@company.com"
$MailSubject = '-Subject Certifikat expiring within 90 days'
$MailBody = '-Body ?'
$SendReportNow = 'Send-MailMessage $MailSMTP $MailFrom $MailTo $MailSubject'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers { Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My } | ForEach { 
If ($_.NotAfter -le $Deadline -and $_.Issuer -like '*CertainCompanyName*') { $_ | Select @{Label="Servername";Expression={($_.PSComputerName)}}, Issuer, Subject, @{Label="Expiry Date & Time";Expression={($_.NotAfter)}}, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned your code up, hopefully this is easier to digest.

```
$Servers = 'testserver1','testserver2'
$Threshold = 400000 
$Deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($Threshold)

$certs = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers { Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My } 

ForEach ($cert in $certs){
    If ($cert.NotAfter -le $Deadline -and $cert.Issuer -like '*CertainCompanyName*') { 
        $body = $cert | Select @{Label="Servername";Expression={($cert.PSComputerName)}}, Issuer, Subject, @{Label="Expiry Date & Time";Expression={($cert.NotAfter)}}, @{Label="Expires In (Days)";Expression={($cert.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}}
        $MailSubject = "[$($cert.PsComputerName)] Certifikat expiring within 90 days"
        Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtpserver.domain.com -Port 25 -From sendersmailaddress@company.com -To receiversmailaddress@company.com -Subject $MailSubject -Body $body
    }
}
```

This will result in e-mails being sent like this:

```
Title:              [ServerA] Certifikat expiring within 90 days
-----  Body-------
Servername         : ServerA
Issuer             : CN=localhost
Subject            : CN=localhost
Expiry Date & Time : 4/5/2020 8:00:00 PM
Expires In (Days)  : 1627
```

Comment: Thanks...almost perfect except that the output email is show as: @{ServerA.........and also the the need of formatting the output as everything sticks togheter without line separation is needed (I'm using Lotus Notes at work=virus itself, it that would matter). Also time needs to be formatted like "2015-10-23 12:22". I am working on it myself, thought I'd just let you know!

Comment: I manage to fix the problem.....apparently I slammed my head onto the wall a little too much.... in your send-mailmessage line. Add -Body ($body | out-string). This with Powershell 4